# I want to combine two columns into a new column, but only if one isn't blank, and then sort by that new column. (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Let's say I have two columns, city and sitename.

```
City        Sitename
Boston      Hynes Convention Center 
Baltimore   The Sheraton 
NYC         Times Square
            Applebees 
Tuoson       
Beijing     
            My Backyard
```

I've purposefully left some fields in either column blank, and here's why.  When I output this information using PHP, I want it to come out in the form {city} - {sitename}, but ONLY if they're both not blank.  If either one is blank, then I just want it to show {city} or {state}, whichever it is.  Then, once I have this new column of combined (or not) values, I want to sort my data by this new column A - Z.  So in the end it should appear something like this...

```
City         Sitename                  Combined
             Applebees                 Applebees
Baltimore    The Sheraton              Baltimore - The Sheraton
Beijing                                Beijing
Boston       Hynes Convention Center   Baltimore - Hynes Convention Center
             My Backyard               My Backyard
NYC          Times Square              NYC - Times Square
Tuoson                                 Tuoson
```

I've combined and renamed columns and done sorting before, but trying add in the conditions and cases is having me scratching my head.

Oh and this isn't a table alteration, it's how I want to retrieve the data.  So the statement should be something like...

"SELECT * FROM table... "

Comment: So far I've done the sorting beforehand and then the combining on the PHP side.  So I'll have the table sorted by city, then sitename, then something like  "echo $row['city'] - $row['sitename']".  That's not the exact statement, there's more conditions, but the end result is almost what I want, except that when I have blank fields the data comes out sorted wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested, I apologize.

```
Select Trim(BOTH ' - ' From Concat(Coalesce(city, ''), ' - ', Coalesce(sitename, ''))) As citysite
From my_table
Order By citysite
```

I believe MySQL lets you order by an aliased column. If that's not the case, then simply copy the Trim() contents into the Order By as well.

Comment: Trim on NULL returns NULL, and concatenating to NULL returns NULL

Comment: There's no NULLs in my table, only blank strings.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I added in a little coalesce action to help our little MySQL baby calm down. @Mathias: this version will help if you have NULL instead of empty strings as either city or sitename.

Comment: OK thanks.  I'm not sure what Coalesce or BOTH keywords do, but I'll be sure to look those up so I know for future reference.  Thanks again!

Comment: Coalesce takes the first non-null value in the list of parameters you send it. In this case, it will get city if it's not null, otherwise it sort of defaults to an empty string. BOTH is an argument of TRIM(), which says to remove the following string of characters from both sides of the trimmable string. There is also a LEFT and RIGHT you could pass in.

Comment: I've noticed one slight thing.  I have "Brooklyn (Canarsie) - Paerdegat Basin" put before "Brooklyn - Deadhorse Bay".  It seems like it's sorting "(" before "-" rather than following the convention of shorter words before longer words.  It's not a big deal really, just something I noticed.

Comment: I think you might be able to change that with the table's collation, but that would be another question. As a little test, you could try creating a quick table with that whole thing as the value to see if it sorts it that way anyway, regardless of the whole TRIM() thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(City,'') as City, 
   COALESCE(Sitename,'') AS Sitename, 
   CASE 
     WHEN COALESCE(City,'')='' THEN Sitename
     WHEN COALESCE(City,'')<>'' AND COALESCE(Sitename,'')='' THEN City
     ELSE City + ' - ' + Sitename 
   END AS Combined
FROM table
ORDER BY 
 CASE 
  WHEN COALESCE(City,'')='' THEN Sitename
  WHEN COALESCE(City,'')<>'' AND COALESCE(Sitename,'')='' THEN City
  ELSE City + ' - ' + Sitename 
 END
```

It should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Doesn't handle zero length strings, which aren't null

Comment: 15 lines of sql to get one column of data... funny definition of "straght forward" ;)

Comment: Looks like someone was raised on a steady diet of Microsoft products.

Comment: I don't see what the fuss is about. It is a quite standard query that should run on just about any rdbms. it'll handle NULL values and empty values (which the poster did not specify anything about). Also, writing it long doesn't mean it's slow, and it's written like this to be easy to read. But sure, each to his/hers own taste :)

Comment: I think the point is that it's NOT easy to read, except perhaps to the author ;) It's much more difficult to understand what's going on than other solutions due to the wordiness.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT case when city is null then
           sitename
       else
           city || ' - ' || sitename
       end 
FROM table
```

?

Comment: Needs to handle a null `sitename` as well.

Comment: NVL is oracle for COALESCE - ish :)

Comment: Gives me a column full of 0s.  Pretty sure Oracle-style SQL doesn't mesh well with MySQL

Comment: Doesn't handle null for both columns, and isn't ordered.

Comment: @Mathias Schnell: MySQL might need ANSI strictness turned on -- the `||` is the ANSI means of concatenating strings in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  City + ' ' + Sitename   
where City ....
  and Sitename ...
order by City + ' ' + Sitename
```

Comment: This is missing a "From" statement.

Comment: did you remove the dots? and replaced with an apropiate condition as you asked